# Expected Percentage of Red Nodes in Left Leaning Red Black Tree Program?

Tags: java, red-black-tree

I modified a left-leaning red black tree program from a textbook to count the number of red nodes after inserting N distinct integers in the range of 1 to N for an assignment. I consistently get a percentage of of 52%-54%, for a N of 10^4, 10^5, and 10^6 when using an array of random integers created by the Java class Random.

Is this in a an acceptable range or should it be lower than that? I think about it in my head and I feel it should be lower so I was wondering if I made a mistake.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The percentage should definitely be lower, around 30-35%. What algorithm are you using to calculate your percentage?

Comment: Yeah it was because I naively used the random function in java for my test array, which did not do what it was intended to. I instead used a shuffle algorithm to shuffle an array of 1 to N integers in order to create a random array and received results around 25% which I think is more accurate.

Comment: Thanks for replying though!